# Alternatives to github network graph viewer?

Tags: git, github

When I click the "forks" button on github, I want to get a summary, which is what I get with the network graph viewer - but it's not exactly ideal.

What I would *ideally* like is a summary that:

- shows commit messages and lists changed files
- excludes commits and branches that have been merged into other branches
- excludes commits and branches that have been merged into other branches, even if git doesn't "know" that they have been merged (i.e. a cherry pick or rebase rather than an explicit git merge or pull)
- give some indication of the "momentum" of a fork (e.g. commit rate, number of forks that have forked from it instead of forking from the original, etc.) so you can realise when a fork is heading towards becoming the de facto standard version.
- works with any given list of related repositories, in addition to github forks

In terms of usability, it should ideally:

- work well on a touchscreen device (where you can't hover the pointer, and the browser may already be using gestures for navigation, so you have to resort to an [on-screen] keyboard to scroll the github network graph). This could mean just a completely textual UI, or it could mean a GUI that doesn't use tooltips.
- work well for "fat-fingered" users (which includes touchscreen users, but also disabled/elderly users). It can be frustrating having to click or hover on a tiny little point to see a commit. It doesn't have to be that way.

The tool wouldn't necessarily have to show the graph relationships between branches. I'm generally most interested in what has changed, and most forks that I look at are simple linear forks anyway.

This would be particularly useful for repos with lots of forks.

I don't mind if the tool has to fetch all branches from all forks from github to do this (though it might make sense to make this a public, web-based app with some form of caching, to reduce the load on github for popular or heavily-forked repos).

Comment: Btw there is an unofficial bug report for it: https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/175

Comment: May not be directly related but I wrote a userscript for network page: https://github.com/maliayas/github-network-ninja

Answer (score 5):

something like this? http://dev.choonkeat.com/branchesapp/

Comment: Yes! Is it available for download?

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/choonkeat/branchesapp