# GitHub - how to find original author after zillion of social forks?

Tags: github

On GitHub someone fork a project, next this project also is forked and so on...

How to find original page/author of the project on GitHub?

Is it possible to view a social graph of *forks*?

How can one know if two repositories unrelated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to view social graph of forks?

Yes, it is called the "[Network Graph Visualizer](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer)"

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a44a44c4d892b8e9f9dbd53a99ee0ec5da92d29b/687474703a2f2f696d672e736b697463682e636f6d2f32303038303431302d6262377731356a6e336d386432716b756d357764676e726a33622e706e67]

The "original" repo is the one with the oldest commit.  This can be accessed via the project page, click *Insights* top tab then click left-side tab *Network* (using Desktop browser, as of January 2019).

An alternative to list forks of a repo is [**branchesapp**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9556680/6309).

Answer (score 1):

> How to find original page/author of project on GitHub?

As of Januhairy 2021, clicking on the number next to `Fork` button shows the original project.

> How to know if two repositories unrelated?

Everything is connected.